# Div is empty. With jQuery...false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this div (`<div id="slideshow">`).
In index.php is full.
In the other pages is empty. (I use Joomla, and that is a module).
Now, when is full, it's ok.
But, when it's empty, I want change a css property of next div.
(`<div id="slideshow">...</div><section>....</section>`).
Now, I try this code :

```
            alert($("div#slideshow").text() == "");
            alert($("div#slideshow").is(':empty'));
```

The result in all pages are: False , False.
False??? for all?
p.s. for empty I want to say this (`<div id="slideshow"></div>`).
Thanks for the answer.

---

I understood where wrong.
With chrome I saw (`<div id="slideshow"></div>`), but copying it as html gave me this:

```
<div id="slideshow">

             </div>
```

So it's not empty!
Now I wonder, how do I proceed?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? it doesn't seem right...

Comment: You must have another element with id of slideshow, this fiddle works using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/KFgq3/

Comment: You could try: alert($("div#slideshow").text().trim() == "");

Comment: Your php code probably generates some newlines and spaces.

Comment: Thanks to @noShowP.
I resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trimming the whitespaces before comparing with an empty string?

```
$.trim( $('#slideshow').text() ) == ''
```

Answer (score 1):

The text of this element is `!= ""` but it is empty:

```
<div> </div>
```

Comment: excuse me, but if the thext of this element is =="" , why the result is ever false??

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("div#slideshow").html()`

"In an HTML document, .html() can be used to get the contents of any element" - http://api.jquery.com/html/

"The result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements" - http://api.jquery.com/text/